# 12 identical balls and 3 teams

Tags: probability, combinations

I was wondering for the following question:

There’s a box with 12 identical balls.

1) In how many ways 3 teams can pick them given that each can hold a maximum of 10 balls.

2) How many ways each team can pick them given that each team can pick a maximum of 10 balls and a minimum of 1 ball?

A step by step explanation will be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to find it by contradiction:

1) What is the total number to distribute the balls among the teams? (stars-and-bars)

2) In how many ways a team can have more than 10?

3) You have 3 teams.

4) Subtract this number from $\binom{14}{2}$ to get what you need.

Comment: Thanks for response. Can you please elaborate. There are 12 balls.

Comment: 14 = 12+3-1, i.e. you have 14 positions for 2 bars and 12 stars. Can yo handle from here?

Comment: 9 comes from the fact that if one team has 11 balls, you have 2 outcomes for other teams; if it has 12 balls, there's only one outcome; now, you have 3 teams.

Answer (score 0):

ooooo|oooo|ooo
Could be one representation of the allocation between balls between teams.
i.e. 5 balls to team 1, 4 balls to team 2, 3 balls to team 3.

How many ways can we allocate circles and pipes (or more traditionally "stars and bars")?

There are 2 pipes and 14 objects total  ${14\choose2}$

So this is all of the ways to allocate 12 balls.

How many ways to allocate 10 balls such that no one has more than 10?

Lets answer this question instead: How many ways to allocate 10 balls such that someoene has at least 10?

Give 10 to 1 team allocate the rest.

There are 2 balls to distribute (and 2 pipes) ${4\choose2}$
And there are 3 teams that could be the "rich team"

$3\cdot{4\choose2}$

Since there is a question here. Lets enumerate the cases.  I say there are 18 
cases.

(10,2,0), (10,1,1), (10,0,2), (11,1,0), (11,0,1), (12,0,0) (that is 6 so far),

(2,10,0), (1,10,1),(0,10,2), (1,11,0),(0,11,1), (0,12,0) (another 6)

and 6 when team 3 gets the big pile of balls.

How many ways to allocate 10 balls such that no one has more than 10?

${14\choose2}-3\cdot{4\choose2}$

How many ways to allocate 10 balls such that no one has more than 10, and every team has at least one?

It is impossible for a team to have more than 10 balls, if every team has at least one.

Give one ball to each team.  Allocate the rest
that leaves 9 balls to distribute (and 2 pipes)

${11\choose2}$

Comment: thanks. I liked the approach. Please elaborate why 3 is multiplied choose(4,2)

Comment: Answer given in book for first part is 15C2 – 9  and answer for second one is 11C9 . I was wondering whether its typo..

Comment: 11C9 = 11C2.  Not sure where 15C2 - 9 comes from, that seems too high.  Regarding 3 (4C3), I will detail it in the post.